# List all dates between a range

Tags: google-sheets

I am trying to get all dates between a range to be split into separate cells.  How do I do this?

start (a1): 15/8/2015
finish (b1): 18/8/2015

Which then lists:

c1: 16/8/2015
d1: 17/8/2015

Answer (score 0):

Please try, in C1 and copied across until no value is shown:

```
=if(and($A1+column()-2<$B1,int($B1)>int($A1)),$A1+column()-2,"")
```

Comment: Getting this: Error
Function ADD parameter 1 expects number values. But '16/8/2015' is a text and cannot be coerced to a number.